# PHP mail() win64

Tags: php, email, xampp, localhost, win64

Is it possible to use PHP `mail()` on localhost in 64-bit Win10?
I use xampp to run localhost and tried to use this function,
but it returns error `Socket Error #10060<EOL>Connection timed out`.
I used this configuration on 32-bit Win and there was no problem,
mails were sent without any errors.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

To send mail in gmail  account
->In sendmail(inside wamp folder) folder open file “sendmail.ini” in notepad for editing

Change the below line in this file
*smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com* //if u r using gmail id

Answer (score 0):

```
a) Open the "php.ini". For XAMPP,it is located in C:\XAMPP\php\php.ini. Find out if you are using WAMP or LAMP server. Note : Make a backup of php.ini file

b) Search [mail function] in the php.ini file.

You can find like below.
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25


; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
;sendmail_from = postmaster@localhost


Change the localhost to the smtp server name of your ISP. No need to change the smtp_port. Leave it as 25. Change sendmail_from from postmaster@localhost to your domain email address which will be used as from address..

So for me, it will become like this.
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
SMTP = smtp.example.com
smtp_port = 25
; For Win32 only.
sendmail_from = info@example.com


c) Restart the XAMPP or WAMP(apache server) so that changes will start working.

d) Now try to send the mail using the mail() function ,

mail("example@example.com","Success","Great, Localhost Mail works");
```

Mail will be sent to "example@example.com" from the localhost with Subject line "Success" and body "Great,Localhost Mail works"

Comment: It works only for email adress from my ISP?
I send mail for xxx@example.com and it works,
but when I try send it to xxx@gmail.com then
nothings happen.

Comment: The original question was for Win64, while your answer says "For Win32 only". Does this work with Win64?